# confluent kafka connect elasticsearch sink throughput drops permanently after task restart

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a topic with 7 million records (3 partitions) and deploy an Elasticsearch sink with 1 task using mostly the default configurations. The sink starts by creating the index in Elasticsearch and then starts writing at a rate of 10,000 msgs/second. If I make any changes to the connector's tasks

- pause the connector, restart the task, start the connector
- leave connector running but restart the task

The throughput drops to 400 msgs/second and never recovers to the original 10,000/sec.

If I stop the connector, delete the index from Elasticsearch and resume the connector it goes back to sinking 10k messages/sec.

I've tried changing the connector configs away from the defaults with no results.

```
connection.timeout.ms=1000
batch.size=2000
max.retries=5
max.in.flight.requests=5
retry.backoff.ms=100
max.buffered.records=20000
flush.timeout.ms=10000
read.timeout.ms=3000
```

**My connector config**

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
type.name=logdata
errors.log.include.messages=true
tasks.max=1
topics=d8.qa.id.log.sso.transformed.0
key.ignore=true
schema.ignore=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
elastic.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
name=elasticsearch-sink-d8.qa.id.log.transformed
connection.url=http://172.30.2.23:9200,http://172.30.0.158:9200,http://172.30.1.63:9200
client.id=elasticsearch-sink-d8.qa.id.log.transformed
```

**Environment Details**

```
Elasticsearch 6.8 (10 data nodes, 3 master)
Elasticsearch connector (version 2.2.1)
Kafka Connect (2 workers with 16GB memory, version 2.2.1)
Kafka Broker (3 brokers with 32GB memory, version 2.2.1)
```

NOTES:

- Same behaviour with ES 7.2 and Elasticsearch connector version 2.3.1
- This is the only connector on deployed to the connect cluster

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue for the Confluent Platform 5.3.x and below caused by the index not being cached if the index isn't created by `JestElasticsearchClient`. The fixes [PR-340](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/pull/340) and [PR-309](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/pull/309) have been merged and will be deployed with Confluent Platform 5.4.